# Creating a trigger AFTER UPDATE to Update another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on a table after Update, which gonna update another table.

this is the code I tried :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update_quantite_article` AFTER UPDATE ON `LigneInterventaire` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE qte AS INTEGER;
SET qte = NEW.qteInv - OLD.qteInv;
UPDATE Article 
     SET qteArt := qteArt + qte
   WHERE codeArt = NEW.codeArt
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

but I get this error message :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS INTEGER; SET qte = NEW.qteInv - OLD.qteInv; UPDATE Article
>   SET qteArt =' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Did you have a question? I'm going to interpolate, and expect you were asking a question such as "How do I fix this?". A more plain reading would be that you are providing a report on the status of your current development efforts.)

To fix this, simply move the `DECLARE` statement after the `BEGIN`.

ALSO, replace references to `@qte` with simply `qte`.  (i.e. I recommend you use a procedure variable instead of a user variable. If you don't know the difference, then it's likely that a procedure variable is what you really want here.)

It looks like you avoid using a variable altogether, if the `qteInv` column is defined as INTEGER type, you aren't relying on a conversion to character (as in the case with the user variable), or counting on some other special handling introduced with variables.

It would be easier on future readers of your code to have it more simply be written:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_quantite_article` AFTER UPDATE ON `LigneInterventaire`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Article
     SET qteArt = qteArt + ( NEW.qteInv - OLD.qteInv )
   WHERE codeArt = NEW.codeArt
END
```